# Android use react-native-vector-icons on Java

Tags: android

i found this fonts on `React Native` github repository and i want to use them on my application, i'm using `fontawesome` fonts from [this link](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) now

for example

```
fontPath="fonts/fontawesome.ttf"
android:text="&#xf0ab;"
```

how can i use react native fonts from [this link](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/tree/master/Fonts) which they are `TTF` like with above code on `xml` layout?

how can i use Cheatsheet like with fontawesome for react native fonts? other fonts like with that?

Answer (score 0):

try this **Create a Helper Class**

```
public class FontManager {

    public static final String ROOT = "fonts/",
    FONTAWESOME = ROOT + "fontawesome.ttf";

    public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, String font) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font);
    }    

}
```

than use like this

```
Typeface iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(getApplicationContext(), FontManager.FONTAWESOME);
FontManager.markAsIconContainer(findViewById(R.id.icons_container), iconFont);
```

for more information visit this link **[how to use fontawesome](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-fontawesome-in-an-android-app--cms-24167)**

Comment: i dont have any problem on set font to textview, my question is how can i use icons from this fonts. which character must be set to textview? for example use `android:text="&#xf0ab;"` to show bold character

Comment: check the link in ans @Mahdi.Pishguy you can get better idea